# Laravel 5.1 how to make my eloquent query closure secured

Tags: laravel-5.1, php-5.4, eloquent

what i'm trying to do is to **Sum** the total deposits of each reservation model, with the condition of less than the amount input in the text.

here's my query:

```
$reservations->whereHas('deposits', function($query) use ($etc_filters){
    $query->havingRaw('SUM(amount) <= '.$etc_filters);
});
```

as you can see, i'm using havingRaw that can be injected with another query. right now i cant find any alternative solution for my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second argument the [`havingRaw`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_havingRaw) method accepts, to make the value a binding, which gets escaped before it is inserted in the query:

```
$reservations->whereHas('deposits', function($query) use ($etc_filters){
    $query->havingRaw('SUM(amount) <= ?', $etc_filters);
});
```